# How come my function didn't print a output? [Python]

Tags: python, printing

I created a function to square some numbers. I was wondering why my code didn't print.

```
def Square(A):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        A[i] = A[i]**2

A = [2,0,-3]

print(Square(A))
```

Comment: The function doesn't return anything, it modifies the list in place. Call the function then do `print(A)`

Comment: Or add `return A` to the end of the function (outside the loop).

Answer (score 1):

Add a `return` value.

```py
def Square(A):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        A[i] = A[i]**2
    return A

print(Square(A))
```